# how to draw a line after clicking the "pushbutton" in qt

Tags: qt, signals-slots, paintevent

```
    #include "widget.h"
    #include "ui_widget.h"
    #include <ostream>

    Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Widget)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        p1 = new QPoint;
        p2 = new QPoint;

        connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
    }

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    Widget *ff = new Widget(this);
    ff->curveProcess();

}
```

after clicking, set the point to draw ,the label was showed as expected;

```
void Widget::curveProcess() {

        QLabel  label;
        label.setText("hahaha");
        label.show();
        p1->setX(0);
        p1->setY(0);
        p2->setX(100);
        p2->setY(100);
        update();

    }
```

p1 and p2 were declared in header file using QPoint *p1;
    QPoint *p2;void virtual paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);

```
void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        QPainter painter(this);
       painter.drawLine(*p1,*p2);

    }
```

After clicking the pushbutton,the label is showed,I think that means the slot works well,but I got no line at all.I am a fresh man in Qt,thanks all sincerely

Comment: You have to: 1) Remove this line: `Widget *ff = new Widget(this);` 2) Replace `ff->curveProcess();` with `curveProcess();`. The problem is that you create another instance of your `Widget` class, define points there, but want to draw on your original instance.

Comment: Thank you,it works!! This problem has tortured me  for several days.Thanks  again for your help!